# How to return the promises inside the ajax .done?

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am creating the word AddIn. The below mentioned function is calling from the button onclick which is written in the xml file.
My problem is, I'm trying to get the tag name using the contentController and replacing the values with new values, but currently I'm trying to get the length of the item and inserting in document but this is not working.

```
function setUp()
{
    Word.run(function (context){

        var endpoint  = "https://graph.microsoft.....";
        $.ajax({
            url:endpoint,
            async:false,
            dataType:'json',
            type:'GET',
            cache:'false',
            headers:{ 'Authorization':'Bearer '+token}
        }).done(function (json)
        {
            context.document.body.insertParagraph("some paraga","End");//This is loading

            // I'm trying to get the elemnet By tag
            //Below content is not loading

            var selectedTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag");
            context.load(selectedTag,'text');
            return context.sync().then(function()
            {
                context.document.body.insertParagraph(selectedTag.items.length,"End");
            });

        });

    })
}
```

About [contentController](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/word/contentcontrol.md)

Comment: Quick question. Rather than using promises, why not just run something else once the ajax function has reached success/false? Also, why have you set `async` to false if you don't mind me asking? I'm just curious more than anything else.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I have tried the `async function fname()` this is working in the scriptlab add in. Using that function we can use the `await context.sync()` to write the content inside the document. But the problem is I'm not able call async function inside the AddIn.

Comment: interesting... I see.... Hmm... Gimme a sec, I may have a trick or two up my sleeve....

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of... using `$when(func).done( ... ) ... func () {/* contains your ajax code*/ }`? You may be thinking of course I have, and to be fair, you have presented some code, but I'm still not fully aware of what you've tried and what you haven't tried. I hope this is actually helpful either way!

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I have searched on the web, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins) says by default it will take the IE11 browser. That the response which is not supporting the `async` `await` `sync` methods. I have tried  `$when`  but I when passing the variable to the function it is not responding anything.

Comment: Please show more code, I'm wondering *how* you're implementing `$wait`?

Comment: Are you sure there is a rich text content control tagged with `myTag`? Is it possible it isn't in the document?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Yes `myTag` contain the rich text. In the documentation says by default browser is IE11 and we can use all other browsers but I not able to integrate the other browser in addIn

Comment: With Office 2013 and 2016 for Windows, it uses an embedded IE 11 instance. Since add-ins work across platforms and browsers, IE 11 becomes the defacto baseline. This is unlikely to change so long as Windows 7 is a supported platform.